# VSCode extension developmet: convert x, y coordinates on the screen to line, column number in the file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, data-conversion

I'm now trying to develop a VSCode extension, which aims to **convert x, y coordinates of the screen data to line, column number of code file**. But I cannot even get the size and location of text editor.

Visual Studio and Eclipse has interface like `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.ITextView` or `org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText` to complete the task, but I haven't found similar interface in VSCode.

The `TextEditor` and `TextDocument` class in VSCode Extension API have some attributes like `visibleRanges` or `lineAt` but they only measure position with line, character number. I can't find the function connecting between screen pixels with them.

Comment: for what reason do you need x,y coords on screen, you manipulate text that has scrolls, zooms, font sizes,..... all taken care of for you by VSC, you only need line-char positions. Use a webview and write your own editor

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is because I'm now using eye tracking to research some software engineering issues. The data generated from eye tracking is x, y coordinates, thus I want to convert them into row and columns...

Comment: then you have to calibrate the x,y coords for a particular font setting, and keep track of the visible range for the vertical scroll, but the scroll can be a partial line